# PhpWord replace image with text

Tags: php, ms-word, phpword

I am trying to replace a looped image in a word template using PHPWord and I have found a solution [here](https://github.com/OAFCROB/PHPWord/blob/ca52b0997a333e24a2ffe21eb93a9147f657dcf4/src/PhpWord/TemplateProcessor.php) but the output file says "We are sorry. We cant open out because we found a problem with its content".

My code looks like

```
foreach($response as $key => $value) {
$templateProcessor->setImageValue('testPhoto#'.$key,'image1.jpeg','favicon'.$key.'.png');
}
```

In my [word template](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/43068636/sales_narrative.docx) I have an image with an alt text as ${testPhoto}. I have copied all the remaining code recommended in the link.

Please help.

Comment: can you attach the word doc aswell?

Comment: @eFriend Thanks for your reply. Please check the document I have linked.